# Laravel 9 - How to display the number of my products from my shopping basket?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm creating a shop on Laravel 9 and I would like to add a shopping basket with the number of products I have added on my 'paniers' SQL table.

I wrote this on my controller :

```
    public function AffichageBoutique()
    {
        $boutiques = Boutique::all();
        $nbr = Panier::where('iduser', session('iduser'))->get()->count();
        return view('boutique.Boutique')->with('boutiques', $boutiques)->with('paniers', $nbr);
    }
```

$nbr is the number of my products I have on my basket, for example -> 4.

I would like to display this number on my page like this, it's an animated basket =>

```
            <div class="icon-wrapper">
            <figure>
                <img src="/img/icons/bell_icon.svg" alt="" class="bell-icon">
                <figcaption>
                    <p>{{ $nbr }}</p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
```

But I have this error : Undefined variable $nbr.

What's the problem ??
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```php
public function AffichageBoutique() {
     $boutiques = Boutique::all();
     $nbr = Panier::query()
          ->where('iduser', session('iduser'))
          ->count(); //Just grab the count.
     
     return view('boutique.Boutique', [
         'boutiques' => $boutiques,
         'nbr' => $nbr
     ])
}
```

And then for your view:

```html
<div class="icon-wrapper">
     <figure>
          <img src="/img/icons/bell_icon.svg" alt="" class="bell-icon">
          <figcaption>
               <span>({{ $nbr }})</span>
          </figcaption>
      </figure>
</div>
```

I'd also suggest returning "$nbr" as something more explicit, like,
$user_panier_cart_total or $card_total maybe.

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('boutique.Boutique')->with('boutiques', $boutiques)->with('paniers', $nbr);
```

in your return you are passing the `$nbr` variable and renaming it as `'paniers'`, either you change the name to `'nbr'` (`->with('nbr', $nbr)`) or in your html you call for `$paniers`

You can find more in [Laravel official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#passing-data-to-views)